# couldn't find ".setting" folder in maven project

Tags: eclipse, maven

I created a maven project with eclipse stored the file  in my desktop ,but i couldn't find "/.setting" folder in my project folder.

[image]

My questions are

1. Where can i find the ".setting" folder?
2. when i go to project properties i couldn't find user setting option under maven.

Answer (score 0):

File and folder names starting with `.` are considered to be hidden by Finder and are not shown.

You can see them in a Terminal session using the `ls -a` command.

Note that the project settings folder is `.settings` not `.setting`.

Comment: your answer helped me alot.